# How to download security updates for Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04

Which command should I use to download security uodates for Ubuntu Hardy?

Ideally would like the command to also create a log file listing files downloaded, install and any errors.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good start:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get upgrade
```

And check /var/log/dpkg.log and /var/log/apt/term.log

Comment: @rkthkr. I thought apt-get upgrade will upgrade a package to the newsest version, which I do not want. I only want to update and install security updates for a package. 

Can you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it will be a newer package, but the upstream version will be the same, no new features added only security fixes (sometimes there are a new version if the fix is not backportable or the upgrade is safe.)

Comment: For someone not familiar with it: The reason you get the same upstream version is the policy of the distribution maintainers and not a technical one. The maintainers of Ubuntu try to give you a stable (not requiring configuration changes or changed user experience while the distribution version stays the same) and secure (most recent security patches: maybe they even backport fixes if upstream has advanced their software in the meantime) platform over the maintenance timeframe. In extreme cases (ClamAV) they would also switch to a new upstream version if security/functionality requires it.